# How to login via url

Tags: login

Any way to login direct with URL without user need type user and password?
I need some simple to run in my intranet.

Some like http://mydomain.com/?user=name?password=9999

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Questions seeking coding support are expected to post their efforts: research / code.

Comment: May I ask why you are doing this? Aren't you concerned about storing an unencrypted password in this url string?

Comment: You're going to want to do this via a token, as opposed to displaying the password in the URL

Comment: For the record, a url's querystring begins with a `?` and subsequent key-value pairs are delimited with `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all. I solve with this free extension:

https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/iplogin

Comment: Please remember to resolve this page by awarding the green tick to the answer that you found most helpful (even if that answer is your own).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it but it looks like the free plugin from Acyba will do this for you: https://www.acyba.com/acymailing/282-auto-login-newsletter-joomla.html

The plugin is designed so that links in newsletter emails can contain the username and password as parameters for login but you don't have to include the link to a newsletter.

Answer (score 1):

yes indeed, it works with the acymailing plugin from the free version of acymailing.

Install it and in the plugin options select "plain text for password"

Then try with the following: 
https ://siteadresshere?user=userhere&passw=passwordhere

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for adding some specifics to Neil's recommendation.  Please take our [tour] and considering tell us a bit about your Joomla journey by editing your profile.